# How to create a custom task for control flow and data flow that will appear in SSIS toolbox

Tags: visual-studio, ssis

I want to create a custom SSIS task(control flow and data flow) at SSIS toolbox , so i can easily re-use it like the other tasks(Data Flow Task, Execute SQL Task, etc).

Comment: There are a multitude of guides if you google for them. Keep in mind, SSIS is not really considered modern any more (IMHO)

Comment: check github for an example. Here's one for a control flow task, https://github.com/1996010320/SSIS_RSExecutionTask2014 .

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid why would you say SSIS is not considered modern anymore?

Comment: @Jacques If you're doing data engineering in the Azure cloud for a new project, SSIS would never be considered.

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid what tools are you using for Azure cloud based data engineering?

Comment: Azure data factory, Azure SQL, Databricks.